# noUiSlider + Rails 7 app = Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nouislider

I have a Rails 7 application and I am trying to install noUiSlider (https://refreshless.com/nouislider/).  Installed via yarn and can confirm the source files are in my app.  In my `/app/javascript/application.js` file I added:

```
import noUiSlider from 'nouislider'
```

yet when I try and initialize a slider I get:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined
```

I can see in my application JS file:

```
  // ../../node_modules/nouislider/dist/nouislider.js
  var require_nouislider = __commonJS({
    "../../node_modules/nouislider/dist/nouislider.js"(exports2, module4) {
      (function(global, factory) {
        typeof exports2 === "object" && typeof module4 !== "undefined" ? factory(exports2) : typeof define === "function" && define.amd ? define(["exports"], factory) : (global = typeof globalThis !== "undefined" ? globalThis : global || self, factory(global.noUiSlider = {}));
      })(exports2, function(exports3) {
        "use strict";
        exports3.PipsMode = void 0;
....
```

I seem to be missing something obvious here or a Rails 7 specific issue.

Comment: were you able to solve this?